# Java GraphicsProgram not working

Tags: java

I have this program that is supposed to create a graphics pyramid

```
 import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
public class pyramid extends GraphicsProgram{
  public void run(){
     int bricks_in_base = 12;
     int brick_width = 50;
     int brick_height = 20;
     int base_x = 450;
     int base_y = 100;
  for(int i=1; i==bricks_in_base; i++){
    for(int n=0;n==i; n++){
      int current_x= base_x;
      GRect brick = new GRect(current_x,base_y,brick_width,brick_height);
      add(brick);
      current_x+=50;
     }
    base_x-=25;
    base_y+=20;
  }
 }  
}
```

It compiles ok , but when running it nothing happens, where is the error?

Comment: usually you have to put drawable objects on a canvas object. what does `add` do?

Comment: it adds the brick.The problem is that the "for loop" does not start.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is happening because you are not entering your `for` loop. You set variable `i` to 1, which does not equal the value in `bricks_in_base`, which is 12; this evaluates to `false`, so nothing in your loop will execute.

Either change your condition or change the value stored in `i`. You'll have to do the same for your second loop.

Comment: you probably want `<` or `<=`